# Why do NFL AFC teams play against NFC during season

Tags: nfl, schedule

KC Chiefs played against TB Buccaneers (NFC) months before the Super Bowl : https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/202011290tam.htm I was wondering how come an AFC team plays against a NFC one before they reached the play offs

Comment: Why shouldn’t they?

Comment: because they're in different conferences?

Comment: And in the NBA, MLB, and NHL cross conference play is the norm. More money for TV rights.